# Android Room Persistence library and Kotlin

Tags: database, kotlin, kapt, android-room

I am trying to write a simple app using Kotlin and [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).
I followed [the tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence) in the Android Persistence codelab.

Here is my `AppDatabase` class in Kotlin:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userModel(): UserDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        @JvmStatic fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }

        @JvmStatic fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to run the app, it crashes immediately.
Here is the crash log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.ttp.kotlin.kotlinsample.room.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
    at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:90)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:340)
    at com.ttp.kotlin.kotlinsample.room.AppDatabase$Companion.getInMemoryDatabase(AppDatabase.kt:19)
    at com.ttp.kotlin.kotlinsample.MainKotlinActivity.onCreate(MainKotlinActivity.kt:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
```

It looks like the class `AppDatabase_Impl` wasn't autogenerated. I checked the original java app downloaded from codelab and found that `AppDatabase_Impl` was autogenerated.

Kotlin version: `1.1.2-3`
Room version: `1.0.0-alpha1`

Is there anyone experienced with this?

**Edit:**
Using `kapt` solves my problem. In my case, I have to replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle as well?

Comment: Is there `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"` in your module build.gradle ?

Comment: Thank you. Using kapt plugin solves my problem.

Comment: @ThanhPham i have same issue but adding kapt introduces some gradle errors, please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142964/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlin. Can you provide your gradle file?

Comment: @chandil03 I see you just ADD the kapt. In my case, I have to REPLACE the annotationProcessor BY the kapt.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Usually in project `build.gradle` I define the dependencies versions:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.2'
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    archRoomVersion = '1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

so in app `build.gradle` the dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.supportLibVersion}"

    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"

    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${rootProject.espressoVersion}", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Now you can define Entities Daos and Database in Kotlin.

Database:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

**NB: Query with parameters.**
Kotlin renames params, so the SQL query to retrieve all the emails that belong at a user via the userId is:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM email "
            + "INNER JOIN user ON user.id = email.userId "
            + "WHERE user.id = :arg0")
    fun getEmailsForUser(userId: Int): List<Email>
```

Comment: Thank for you help. In my case, Kotlin renames params to p0, p1... instead of arg0, arg1...

Comment: @Nicola De Fiorenze i have same issue but adding kapt introduces some gradle errors, please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142964/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlin.

Comment: How can I call the `db.userDao().insertAll(user)`?

Comment: Also the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` is needed in the `build.gradle` file as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 39):

In my case, in build.gradle, when you have "annotationProcessor" you need to duplicate with "kapt" and it works.

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lyofen i have same issue but adding kapt introduces some gradle errors, please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142964/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlin.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 12):

Try out these steps

**Step 1.** Set the `room_version` in the `project.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.room_version = '1.0.0-alpha9-1'
...
```

**Step 2.** Apply the `kotlin-kapt` plugin in the `app.gradle` file, and this solved my issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
...
```

**Step 3.** Add the `kapt` dependency in the `app.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Anyone interested in using Kotlin with Room and Data Binding can see this sample project https://github.com/entrpn/kotlin-room-databinding

Answer (score 1):

i almost gave up. but after doing just what dharmin007 said i also had to **clean** the project. that made it work.  I've noticed that whenever you add kapt to gradle you MUST clean the project after synching gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a necessity to my answer I know that some of the above answers already included this to their answers but they added other things

ONLY ADD 
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`