# Room Persistence lib implementation in Kotlin(Gradle error)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am implementing Room persistence lib in kotlin for my database implementation.
Same question is asked in [Android Room Persistences library and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065371/android-room-persistences-library-and-kotlin) thread, applying those solution resulted in different gradle errors:

Following are my `Entity`, `Dao` and `Database` classes:

**Food.kt**

```
@Entity
class Food(@ColumnInfo(name = "food_name") var foodName: String,
           @ColumnInfo(name = "food_desc") var foodDesc: String,
           @ColumnInfo(name = "protein") var protein: Double,
           @ColumnInfo(name = "carbs") var carbs: Double,
           @ColumnInfo(name = "fat") var fat: Double)
{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "calories")
    var calories: Double = 0.toDouble()
}
```

**PersonalizedFood.kt**

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = arrayOf("food_id","date"))
class PersonalizedFood(@ColumnInfo(name = "quantity") var quantity: Int,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "unit") var unit: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: Date){

    @ColumnInfo(name = "food_id")
    var foodId:Long = 0
}
```

**FoodDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface FoodDao {

    companion object{
        const val ID = "id"
        const val NAME = "name"
        const val PROTEIN = "protein"
        const val DESC = "desc"
        const val CARBS = "carbs"
        const val FAT = "fat"

        const val DATE = "date"
        const val FOOD_ID = "food_id"

        const val ALL_FOOD_LIST = "food"
        const val PERSONALISED_FOOD_LIST = "personalised_food"
    }

    /**
     * Returns food details of a food given by food_id
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $ALL_FOOD_LIST WHERE $ID=:food_id")
    fun getFoodDetails(food_id:Long):Food

    /**
     * Inserts food items in all_food_list
     */
    @Insert
    fun addFoodList(list:ArrayList<Food>)

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun saveFood(food:PersonalizedFood)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $PERSONALISED_FOOD_LIST WHERE $FOOD_ID=:foodId and $DATE=:date")
    fun getFood(foodId:Int, data:Date):PersonalizedFood

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $ALL_FOOD_LIST where $ID in (select $FOOD_ID from $PERSONALISED_FOOD_LIST where $DATE = :date)")
    fun getFood(date:Date):ArrayList<Food>
}
```

**Converter.kt**

```
class Converter {

    companion object{
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
            return if (value == null) null else Date(value)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date): Long {
            return date.time
        }
    }
}
```

**FoodDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Food::class, PersonalizedFood::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
abstract class FoodDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun foodDao():FoodDao

    companion object{
        private val databaseName = "diet"

        var dbInstance:FoodDao? = null
        fun getInstance(context:Context):FoodDao?{
            if(dbInstance == null)
                dbInstance = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, FoodDatabase::class.java).build().foodDao()
            return dbInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run following code to create database:

`FoodDatabase.getInstance(baseContext)?.getFood(Calendar.getInstance().time)`

It gives me following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.chandilsachin.diettracker.database.FoodDatabase. FoodDatabase_Impl does not exist
                                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:90)
                                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:340)
                                                                                   at com.chandilsachin.diettracker.database.FoodDatabase$Companion.getInstance(FoodDatabase.kt:21)
                                                                                   at com.chandilsachin.diettracker.MainActivity$SetUpFoodDatabase.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:95)
                                                                                   at com.chandilsachin.diettracker.MainActivity$SetUpFoodDatabase.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:77)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Has anyone implemented room persistence in kotlin?

**Edited**

My previous question on same topic was marked duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065371/android-room-persistences-library-and-kotlin). Though problem statement is same but solution given does not solve my problem. Solution says i have to add replace `annotationProcessor` to `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"` dependency. I made those changes and it resulted in gradle error while project build.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
Warning:warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]'
/Users/BBI-M1025/Documents/BBI/Workspace_fun/Android/diet-tracker/app/src/main/java/com/chandilsachin/diettracker/database/Food.kt
Error:(1, 1) Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please see the error messages above.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
Information:BUILD FAILED in 10s
Information:2 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I am attaching my gradle file also:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chandilsachin.diettracker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ne1c:rainbowmvp:1.2.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.0"

    /*annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"*/

    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Moderators, Please check problem statement before marking as duplicate.

Comment: you can track some issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT and you can also file some bugs if you think its relevant.

Comment: could you check two things?
1. The Kotlin to JVM targhet version (File > Settings > Kotlin compiler) 
2. The project JDK version 
File > Project structure > "JDK location" to see the JDK setted for your project; then go to the setted path, navigate into "bin", and type "java -version"

Comment: @NicolaDeFiorenze JVM target version is 1.6, and java version is "1.8.0_91".

Comment: @chandil03 try to update the JDK, possibly to v1.8.0_121.
I tried to set Kotlin to JVM target to 1.6 and 1.8 without being able to reproduce your error. The java version seems to be the only difference

Comment: @NicolaDeFiorenze problem wasn't with JDK or kotlin version. It was some some gradle config.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spinning my head around for a while with this problem, I came across to the solution.

It was really hard as there is no official tutorial, blog etc out there to help with this problem as of now.

I had to do several hit and trial for all the combination of gradle plugins and dependencies as i knew that something is wrong with gradle config only.

Lets come to the solution:

I had to remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` from build.gradle(:module) file
and replace `annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"` to `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"`.

This is the gradle configuration to successfully compile code.

But there more things to check. You have to initialise properties of your `@Entity class` unlike java given in [Room Persistence lib doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#entities). Though there are getter setter but it is not mentioned to create a constructor with initialisation.
So I had to change my `@Entity` class with this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "all_food_list")
class Food (@ColumnInfo(name = "food_name") var foodName: String = "",
            @ColumnInfo(name = "food_desc") var foodDesc: String = "",
            @ColumnInfo(name = "protein") var protein: Double = 0.0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "carbs") var carbs: Double = 0.0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "fat") var fat: Double = 0.0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "calories") var calories: Double = 0.0)
{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

Now for TypeConverts, Unlike java, you need to create normal function not static functions(companion object):

```
class Converters{

        @TypeConverter
        fun fromTimestamp(value: String): Calendar {
            val arr = value.split("-")
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            cal.set(arr[0].toInt(), arr[1].toInt(), arr[2].toInt())
            return cal
        }

        @TypeConverter
        fun dateToTimestamp(date: Calendar): String {
            return "${date.get(Calendar.DATE)}-${date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1}-${date.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"
        }

}
```

I am adding build.gradle file also to make it more clear:

**build.gradle(:project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    ext.gradle_version_stable = '2.3.2'
    ext.gradle_version_preview = '3.0.0-alpha1'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.0'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chandilsachin.diettracker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
    ...
    // room persistence dependency 
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I think this is all, I did to make my code woking.

Hope this helps someone else also.

Comment: You can also keep your converters as `object` but put `@JvmStatic` on the methods.  That way the generated methods will actually be static and the Room plugin will be happy,

Comment: Adding **default** values to properties solve my problem. It's awful solution. I even think that is a bug.

Comment: @murt its not a bug, as entity classes is not required to have parameterised constructor, it is necessary to have default value.

Comment: Ok but fields in Java may be not initialized, so why var properties have to?

Answer (score 0):

man just add the following in the build.gradle. Above dependencies :D

```
    kapt {
          generateStubs = true
    }
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem of the Impl files not being generated - at least it didn't for me.