# Gradle dependency between tasks

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding, android-room

So this has started happening since adding the new Room android architecture library. I had issues with the AppDatabase_Impl not exsisting, which I fixed by adding kapt to the annotations as:

- [Android Room Persistences library and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065371/android-room-persistences-library-and-kotlin)
- [Room Persistence lib implementation in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142964/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlin)
- [Room Persistence lib implementation in Kotlin(Gradle error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154654/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlingradle-error/)

I had other errors that I suspected were due to AS, Kotlin and Java 8, so I tried updating to AS 3.0

I am now getting the following error when trying to build:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,     :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :cryptocurrency-icons:generateDebugSources, :cryptocurrency-icons:mockableAndroidJar, :cryptocurrency-icons:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :cryptocurrency-icons:compileDebugSources, :cryptocurrency-icons:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :cryptocurrency-icons:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugKotlin
+--- :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug
|    \--- :app:compileDebugKotlin (*)
\--- :app:kaptDebugKotlin
     \--- :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug (*)
(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My gradle files look like:

Project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        targetSdkVersion = 25
        kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
        gradle_version = '2.3.2'
        android_arch_room_version = '1.0.0-alpha1'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.2@aar'
}
```

App gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.application"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Jars
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Modules
    compile project(':cryptocurrency-icons')
    //Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    //Support
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    //OSS
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.9.32.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    //Data binding
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"
    //Room
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$android_arch_room_version"
    kapt  "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$android_arch_room_version"
    //Test
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your project or optimally a MCVE via GitHub or similar?

Comment: https://github.com/RichyHBM/circular-dependency-mcve This is a new android project wiith just the Databinding and Room libraries added as dependencies

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no Android SDK available, but maybe someone else can say something with the MCVE available.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035504/how-to-use-data-binding-and-kotlin-in-android-studio-3-0-0).
Looks like it is a bug in the Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.1.2-4

Answer (score 0):

> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'     //  is deprecated

Try this is

> apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
>
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
>
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Answer (score -1):

remove  line

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in my case remove error  after remove  above line

Answer (score -1):

If you in debug mode please try this `shrinkResources false`, Its working for me.