# Room, Kotlin problems only with JellyBean

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have application in Kotlin where I am using Room library. Application works fine with Android 4.4 and above. But have this issue with android JellyBean (tested 4.1 and 4.2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.app.example.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
                                                                  at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:90)
                                                                  at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:440)
                                                                  at com.app.example.application.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.kt:36)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
```

I tried using

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

No difference. Same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room Persistences library and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065371/android-room-persistences-library-and-kotlin)

Comment: @Ibrahim similar but different. In my case I have problems only with JellyBean. 4.4 and above are working correctly and app configured according google documentation.